# HTTP POST data not going from AJAX to C# MVC 5 Backend

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

As the title states, I'm trying to send data from a Javascript frontend to my C# MVC 5 backend, and it doesn't seem to make it.  I've run through it with the debugger in Visual Studio and the data I'm trying to pass always ends up null.

**Here is my front end code:**

```
var file = $("#my-file").files[0];
file = file[0];
var formData = new FormData();
var MyData = {
    Name: "Form 133",
    Attachments: {
        Type: "Check"
    }
};
formData.append('file', file);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/NMISProduct/Index',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: { formData: formData, MyData: MyData },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

**Backend code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Index(MyData MyData)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Request.Params["MyData"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(MyData.Name);
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
            if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // get a stream
                var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
                // and optionally write the file to disk
                var fileName = fileContent.FileName;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), fileName);
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json("Upload failed");
    }
    return Json("File uploaded successfully");
}

public class MyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Attachment Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

As I stated, on the Backend `MyData` always ends up being null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a thought, but your Index method has only a single parameter, yet your ajax call is passing two parameters: formData, and MyData.  May have something to do with it?

Comment: I think If you are setting `processData` to `false`. You cannot use a JavaScript object as data property, when you do not process the data before sending it. Try to put in a simple string for `MyData` to test if that is being send to the server.

Comment: set traditional: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery docs state:

> **processData** (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean
>   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

The problem is that you are trying to send `MyData` as an object while setting `processData` to `false`. Which will result in the data not being processed before being send. The `data` property should contain a query string of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, or an object of the form `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`, the latter will be converted into a query string before being send unless you are setting `processData` to `false`.

So if you want to send your `formData` along with the `MyData` you will need to append the `MyData` to the `formData` before sending it like so.

```
formData.append('Name', 'Form 133');
formData.append('Type', 'Check');
```

And then in the `$ajax` call add the `FormData` to the `data` property like so.

```
data: formData,
```

Answer (score 0):

**contentType** setting to false you just told him to not sending any data in the header so basically the tag [HttpPost] become useless.

**processData** setting to false you told him not to process has and object so rendering **MyData** useless again by setting to true if i remember correctly it mean process anything beside string has a object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Your METHOD", "Your Controller")",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ MyData: MyData}),
    success: function(response) {
        response ? alert("Process") : alert("Boom");
    }
});
```